# Convert flutter screen to pdf

Tags: flutter, pdf, web, converters

I want to convert the design prepared in my flutter project to pdf, but I don't want to save it as a picture. Because the texts must be selectable. What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to achieve this, but the [`pdf`](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package comes surprisingly close. It offers a Widgets system that is similar to Flutter's. With a little bit of effort, you might be able to refactor your code to use `pdf`'s Widget system and generate a PDF file that looks like your current Flutter UI.